# CSS Conditional comments in LESS CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

While Integrating LESS CSS, I encountered with some conditional comments in CSS like

```
[if IE 7] margin-top: -2px;
[if IE 8] margin-top: -3px;
[if Webkit] margin-top: -1px;
```

And of course they cannot be compiled to CSS by LESS compiler,

So for IE I found a way to avoid conditional comment and make them work, as mentioned [IN THIS ARTICLE](http://tylersticka.com/2012/03/27/happier-ie-fallbacks-with-css-less-and-conditional-comments/)

But, there seems to be no way for [IF Webkit], rather than detecting webkit through JS and adding a class.

Can any body please hep me on this ?

Comment: Those `[if...]` bits are not valid CSS.  If they work at all in a `.css` file, i'd be a bit surprised.

Comment: Conditional comments only work for IE (to be exact IE 5 to 9), there is no way other browsers will render the logic inside conditional comments. Other browsers just see those simply as comments.

Answer (score 1):

You should use conditional comments when specifying which style sheet to use and not inside a stylesheet.. Like so:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_ie6.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Or you should use specific classes inside your css files:

```
.ie6 .container {}
```

and make sure you use the class .ie6 in your html as appropriate

In some cases it might be a good idea to use browser specific stylesheets but i highly recommend that instead of testing for browsers test for features if that is a possibility. Check out [modernizr](http://modernizr.com)

Comment: Ya ! I have done this already... by referring document I mentioned above, but it seems to e working for IE only. Is there any way for [IF webkit]

Comment: I am not sure if there is a `conditional tag` for webkit (just google it) but i highly recommend `feature detection`. check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though technically it is not valid CSS you still can get it via certain escape hacks:

```
.cond(@c, @p, @v) {
    -: ~"; [if @{c}] @{p}: @{v}";
}

div {
    .cond(IE 7,   margin-top, -2px);
    .cond(IE 8,   margin-top, -3px);
    .cond(Webkit, margin-top, -1px);
}
```

This is simplified minimalistic example producing dummy `-: ;` in output (you'll find more gorgeous escape hack examples by searching here for `~"`).

P.S. I'm giving this answer just in case, i.e. to show you can get these strings in LESS, but it does not cancel the fact that this CSS itself is very questionable (`[if Webkit]`? - what browser/library is it supported in?)